# ::webkit scrollbar produces scrollbars of different sizes

Tags: html, css

Here is the codepen I've created to reproduce my table:

https://codepen.io/NazariyV/pen/OoVdWq

For some reason the horizontal and vertical scrollbars are of different sizes, I cannot quite understand why. I have also tried this, which is not picked up at all (even though I see that in the sources, it used the correct .css file):

```
.style-2::-webkit-scrollbar:horizontal
{
    width: 12px!important;
}
```

Codepen HTML:

```
<div class="results-container">

        <div class="header">
            <p class="header-description">Filtered Results</p>
            <span class="additional-description"></span>
            <hr class="underline style-two"/>
        </div>

        <div id="table-scroll" class="table-scroll style-2">
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">Assets</th>
                        <th scope="col">Weights</th>
                        <th scope="col">Weights</th>
                        <th scope="col">Weights</th>
                        <th scope="col">Weights</th>
                        <th scope="col">Weights</th>
                        <th scope="col">Weights</th>
                        <th scope="col">Weights</th>
                        <th scope="col">Weights</th>
                        <th scope="col">Weights</th>
                        <th scope="col">Weights</th>
                        <th scope="col">Weights</th>
                        <th scope="col">Weights</th>
                        <th scope="col">Weights</th>
                        <th scope="col">Weights</th>
                        <th scope="col">Weights</th>
                        <th scope="col">Weights</th>
                        <th scope="col">Weights</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Asset 1</th>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                        </tr>
                <tr>
                            <th>Asset 1</th>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                        </tr>
                <tr>
                            <th>Asset 1</th>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                        </tr>
                <tr>
                            <th>Asset 1</th>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                        </tr>
                <tr>
                            <th>Asset 1</th>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                        </tr>
                <tr>
                            <th>Asset 1</th>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                        </tr>
                <tr>
                            <th>Asset 1</th>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                        </tr>
                <tr>
                            <th>Asset 1</th>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                        </tr>
                <tr>
                            <th>Asset 1</th>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                        </tr>
                <tr>
                            <th>Asset 1</th>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                        </tr>
                <tr>
                            <th>Asset 1</th>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                        </tr>
                <tr>
                            <th>Asset 1</th>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                        </tr>
                <tr>
                            <th>Asset 1</th>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                        </tr>
                <tr>
                            <th>Asset 1</th>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                        </tr>
                <tr>
                            <th>Asset 1</th>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                        </tr>
                <tr>
                            <th>Asset 1</th>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                        </tr>
                <tr>
                            <th>Asset 1</th>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                        </tr>
                <tr>
                            <th>Asset 1</th>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                        </tr>
                <tr>
                            <th>Asset 1</th>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                            <td>0.2</td>
                        </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Codepen CSS:

```
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

.results-container {
    text-align: left;

    width: 85%;
    height: 400px;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 60px;

    background: #ffffffb8;
    border-radius: 2px;

    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);
    transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(.25,.8,.25,1);
}

.results-container:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 14px 28px rgba(0,0,0,0.25), 0 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);
}

.header-description {
    margin: 0;
    display: inline;
    margin-right: 250px;
    position: relative;
    left: 20px;
}

.additional-description {
    margin: 0;
}

.underline {
    margin-top: 2px;
}

.header {
    position: relative;
    top: 20px;
}

.style-2::-webkit-scrollbar-track
{
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

.style-2::-webkit-scrollbar
{
    width: 12px;
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

.style-2::-webkit-scrollbar:horizontal
{
    width: 12px!important;
}

.style-2::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb
{
    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    background-color: #F4F7F7;
}

/* ---------- Risk Scenarios Table ------------- */

.table-scroll {
  position: relative;
  min-width: 730px;
  z-index: 1;
  margin: 35px 20px 0px 15px;
  overflow: scroll;
  height: 325px;
}

.table-scroll table {
  min-width: 1280px;
}

.table-wrap {
  position: relative;
}

.table-scroll th,
.table-scroll td {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background: #fff;
  vertical-align: top;
}

#table-scroll thead th {
  color: #333;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

.table-scroll tfoot,
.table-scroll tfoot th,
.table-scroll tfoot td {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #666;
  color: #fff;
  z-index:4;
}

.table-scroll table th:first-child {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  background: #fff;
}

.table-scroll thead th:first-child,
.table-scroll tfoot th:first-child {
  z-index: 5;
}

body {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

/* ---------------------------------------- HR STYLES ----------------------------------------------------------------*/

hr.style-two {
    border: 0;
    height: 1px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
}

hr.style-four {
    height: 12px;
    border: 0;
    box-shadow: inset 0 12px 12px -12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

/* Custom Outline for Bootstrap drop downs (form control) */
.form-control:focus {
    border-color: #e5382d;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(167, 67, 70, 0.25);
    outline: 0;
}
```

Please note that I also use bootstrap there:
`https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css`.

Comment: need to increase `width`  like  `.style-2::-webkit-scrollbar{width: 16px;}`  Hope this help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out, for **horizontal scrollbar** you have to set **height**.

Add this CSS to your:

```
.style-2::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
}
```

Simple example:

```css
.outer {
  margin: 50px auto;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow: scroll;
}
.inner {
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  background: aqua;
}
.outer::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -moz-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -ms-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -o-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
}
.outer::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
}
.outer::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
  -ms-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
  -o-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
  background-color: #F4F7F7;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    asdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasd
  </div>
</div>
```